# Inserting strings as values in mysql queries

Tags: mysql, c

I want to make Inserts on mysql database,having as values,some string,chars...

This works:

```
if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,'Mercedes',57127)")) {
      finish_with_error(con);
  }
```

How can I do something like this?

```
char str[]="Mercedes";
if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,str,57127)")) {
      finish_with_error(con);
  }
```

In working in C.

Comment: The closest you'll get is with a prepared statement and bound variables. MySQL will **NOT** see your C code, it'll only ever see the sql that gets sent over. And as it stands right now, you'll be opening yourself up to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the two "strings" before passing them down into the library.

Either using the pre-processor:

```
#define str "Mercedes"

...

if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,"str",57127)")) {
  finish_with_error(con);
}
```

Or do it during runtime:

```
char str[] = "Mercedes";
char query_template[] = "INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,%s,57127)"

char query[sizeof str + sizeof query_template - 3];

sprintf(query, query_template, str);

if (mysql_query(con, query, )) {
  finish_with_error(con);
}
```

**Note**: The latter solution introduces a security issue if the content of `str` is provided externally. Do not do this in production code then.

Comment: Why don't you show how to address the security issue with `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Because I am missing the expertise in the MySQL API. Feel free to add it.  @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int id=1,price=123435;
char name[]="mercedez";
char consulta[1024];

sprintf(consulta,"insert into cars values('%d','%s','%d')",id,name,price);
if(mysql_query(con,consulta)==0)
   fprintf(stdout,"datos insertados con exito\n");
```

Comment: This opens up the risk of SQLInjection https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection. You should use prepared statements

Comment: Here is an example: http://lgallardo.com/en/2011/06/23/sentencias-preparadas-de-mysql-en-c-ejemplo-completo/

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
char str[] = "Mercedes";

response = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cars (column1,column2,column3) VALUES 2,'str',57127)");

if(response){ finish_with_error(con); }
```

Comment: That will put the string `str` into the database, not `Mercedes`. C doesn't replace variable inside strings.

Comment: I think you should add str inside '

Comment: It still won't work. You can't put `'str'` in the query, that will not be replaced with `Mercedes`.

Comment: Are you using C language?

Comment: I'm not the questioner, I'm not using anything. But I know C very well, and I know that it will not automatically replace a variable name inside a string with the value of the variable.

Comment: Or I could simply have a char array and just concatenate other chars to it. I test it and works